# Azure Function VS2017 preview tooling - how to bind to CloudBlockBlob?

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

NOTE: I've already solved this, but I'm posting it here anyway so other people can hopefully find the answer more quickly than I did :-)

I have an Azure Functions "class library" project that I created in VS2015, and I'm now trying to migrate that project to the new "Azure Functions" project type in VS2017 15.3 Preview (with Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions).

In VS2015, the C# function signature looks like this:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(HttpRequestMessage req, CloudBlockBlob myFile)
```

and my function.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get"
      ],
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "route": "files/{id}/download"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "name": "myFile",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "inout",
      "path": "mycontainer/{id}",
      "connection": "[my connection string]"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

In VS2017, I have to use binding attributes instead of function.json, so I tried this:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "files/{id}/download")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [Blob("mycontainer/{id}", FileAccess.Read)] CloudBlockBlob myFile)
```

However, when I try to run this I get this error message:

```
[Function Name]: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method '[Function Name]'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Cannot bind blob to CloudBlockBlob using access Read.
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is, even though my code only needs to read (FileAccess.Read) the blob's properties, I need to specify FileAccess.ReadWrite in the binding attribute, like this:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "files/{id}/download")] HttpRequestMessage req,
    [Blob("mycontainer/{id}", FileAccess.ReadWrite)] CloudBlockBlob myFile)
```

I should have remembered that (it's the reason I had to set the binding direction to "inout" in my function.json)... d'oh. As far as I can tell, FileAccess.ReadWrite is the only valid FileAccess value for binding ICloudBlockBlob, CloudBlockBlob or CloudPageBlob values.